# Collecting the output of a remote ssh command in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

How to capture the output of a remote command in a bash script.
For example

```
ssh $USERNAME@$SUT<<EOD
COUNT=$(ls -la | wc -l)
EOD
```

Planning this for a larger script with multiple such instances, where I need to store and use the remote command output.

Answer (score 5):

It should be:

```
VAR=$(ssh "$USERNAME"@"$HOST" -- remote_command -option)
```

You want to execute `remote_command` remotely and store it in a variable locally. That's what the above command does.

If you want to execute a multiline command remotely you use the following construct with a here doc:

```
VAR=$(ssh "$USERNAME"@"$HOST" <<EOF
    remote_command -option
    another_command
    ...
EOF
)
```

Btw, unless you want interpolate local variables into the remote command, you probably want to deactivate local shell expansions in the here doc using `<<'EOF'` as the start delimiter (note the `'`):

```
VAR=$(ssh "$USERNAME"@"$HOST" <<'EOF'
    remote_command -option
    another_command
    ...
EOF
)
```

In the above form you can use shell variables, command substitution etc in the remote script. Like this:

```
VAR=$(ssh "$USERNAME"@"$HOST" <<'EOF'
    COUNT=$(remote_command -option)
    another_command "${COUNT}"
    if $((COUNT+1)) ; then
        foo -bar
    fi
    ... and so on. all expansions happen remotely
EOF
)
```

Comment: wanted to use this format as between first and last line i am planning to write a big logic which need to be executed on the remote machine

Comment: ssh $USERNAME@$SUT<<EOD
COUNT=$(ls -la | wc -l)
if [ $COUNT -eq 4 ]; then
  remote_command2
fi
EOD

Planning to do something like this. Wondering if that is possible

Comment: Use the latter version with the `<<'EOF'` in that case