# Remote command execution here docs & assigning variables

Tags: linux, bash, variables, ssh, scripting

The format, syntax, I have obtained from another post [here][1]
[Collecting the output of a remote ssh command in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117935/collecting-the-output-of-a-remote-ssh-command-in-a-variable[1]):

I am trying to obtain a list of folder contents and compare them with a list of specific processes. I need this to know if all required instances of let's say IHS/WAS are running as expected. I cannot use specific IHS or WAS commands because I do not have access to the commands. I have limited read access to the systems and I am writing a script to obtain list of instances installed, running, etc.

Below is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='xyzhostname'
$vari=$(ssh -T $HOST <<'EOF'
        printf "getting folders: \n"
        instances=$(ls /samplefolder/samplefolder/)
        printf "got folders.\n"
        printf "${instances}"
EOF
 )
```

more code to get processes (ps -ef.....) and compare against each folder obtained in instances above will follow...

I get the below error when I run this code

```
./test.sh: line 9: =getting: command not found
```

Would appreciate any help on this..

Comment: In the shell, you use `$` to *get* the value of a variable, not to *set* it. Try `vari=$(...`. BTW, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting mistakes like this.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I noticed that and updated. it was a typo.